# Using IF with OR, AND and Wildcard in same statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create an IF statement that will basically look at one cell which currently has a macros enabling multi-select drop down from a lookup list.

The field the IF statement is based on is a drop down containing the following information:

```
Android
iOS
PC/Mac
All Devices
Mobile Devices
```

The user can select one value or multiple values.

The IF statement will be true IF, the field contains `All Devices` OR `Mobile Devices` OR `Android` AND `iOS` together. It must also be able to check wildcard as you can select multiple items therefore could be `Android, PC/Mac, iOS` in which case it should be true because both `Android` and `iOS` has been selected.

What should be the actual statement as this is the current one I'm using but I know you can't have wildcard string within this statement:

```
=IF(OR(C7="*-iOS*",C7="*-Android*",C7="Mobile Device",C7="All Delivery Methods",AND(C7="*-iOS*",C7="*-Android*")),"Mobile DTC/ALL","STB (VRP) HD, DEVICE (UVP) HD")
```

Thanks

Edit: If any of the following Scenarios is met and exist in Cell C7, then return the True statement.

Scenario 1: All Delivery Methods
Scenario 2: Mobile Devices
Scenario 3: Android AND iOS

Otherwise return the False statement.

Comment: What is happening with your current formula?

Comment: Why you are using `-` hyphen/minus symbol like `*-iOS`, `*-Android*` etc?

Comment: http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/functions/guide-to-excel-wildcards.htm

Comment: @ashleedawg -  exactly the link from my answer, good job for the SEO of that site :)

Comment: Hi @harun24hr the -/hyphen is only used as it is actually what the value is currently stored as. You can ignore that part.

Answer (score 3):

Excel does not support wildcard statements on all formulas ([see supported formulas](https://exceluser.com/712/)), but you can achieve similar result, if you build a bit your formula.

---

**Solution 1**

E.g., try using `FIND()` with `IFERROR()`. `FIND()` will give you a number, telling you where the searched string is located.

Thus, `=FIND("-Android","tell me more about -Android")`, will give you a number.
If it does not find anything, it will give you a value error, which you may catch with `IFERROR` and return a specific value e.g. `-1`.

Then build the `OR` checking for values bigger than `-1` and you will have what you need.

---

**Solution 2**

Another option is to use `SEARCH()`, which supoports wildcards the way you expect it:

`=SEARCH("test*1";"aaaaaaaatestaaaa1")`

will return 9. [SEARCH in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/search-function-dax)

---

**Solution 3**

In general, there are many ways to build this. As suggested in the comments by @ ImaginaryHuman072889, you may use `ISNUMBER()`. It has the advantage, that it works quite ok with errors, thus you do not need an error catcher for it. Something like this will work ok:

`=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a","b")),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b","b")))`

However, if you change the method from the first solution with an option returning `0` in case of error you would have something like this working as well:

`=OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("a","b"),0),IFERROR(SEARCH("b","c"),0))`

which is quite the same amount of formulas.

---

**Solution 4**

A really interesting solution, avoiding both `OR()` and `IFERROR()`, proposed by @barry houdini. It simply returns `0`, if nothing from the results is found:

```
=COUNT(SEARCH({"a*a";"b*b";"c*c"},"I used to be abba fan."))
```

will return 2, because of `a*a` and `b*b` being found in `abba`. This is how to include the `AND()` of the original question of the OP:

```
=AND(
    COUNT(SEARCH({"a*a";"b*b";"c*c"},"I used to be abba fan.")),
    COUNT(SEARCH({"party*so";"am not"},"but now I am not."))
)
```

Comment: This is not a good answer as it will not solve the current question.

Comment: @harun24hr - which part of the current question would not it solve?

Comment: Your formula will just return `20`. So, is it expected result? May be the questioner is very new in excel.

Comment: @harun24hr - the OP is quite ok with Excel, judging from the point that he uses `OR()` correctly. And the OP asks for wildcards and their usage, not for someone to write the whole formula for him/her.

Comment: @Vityata I agree with this approach except instead of using `IFERROR` to check, I would use `ISNUMBER`, e.g. `ISNUMBER(FIND(...))` will return `TRUE` if a match is found and `FALSE` if a match isn't found. Anyway, still enough for a +1.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - there are plenty of options, depending on the OP and how he wants to build it and debug it. But in general, evaluating to a boolean is probably a better way.

Comment: @Vityata Agreed that there are plenty of options, just that doing `ISNUMBER(FIND(...))` is one less step than `IFERROR(FIND(...),-1)>-1`.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 - if you upgrade a bit the `IFERROR()` solution you achieve the same number of steps, see the edit.

Comment: @Vityata Ah, good point, I always forget that `OR` doesn't have to have logical values as inputs. `0` will effectively be considered as `FALSE` (and anything over `0` is `TRUE`).

Comment: Rather than using OR you could use `COUNT`, e.g. 'IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"a","b","c"},A1)),........`

Comment: Thanks guys. @barryhoudini if I use COUNT can I still use AND with it to check if both values are present, in this case I need also two values to be present for it to flag as true.

Comment: Thanks @Vityata would I still be able to IFERROR with AND to find when I need two values present in the cell to be true? Also, on Stackoverflow how do you actually highlight like you do in the comments?

Comment: @LoosSerine - You can use `AND()` with `IFERROR()` in any formula. Concerning the highlight, you need `15` points to vote up, but you can always mark the answer as accepted - https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @LoosSerine, so if you wanted to check that both "a" and "b" are in cell A1 you can use `=COUNT(SEARCH({"a","b"},A1))=2`...or you could even use COUNTIF with wildcards like `=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,{"*a*","*b*"}))=2`

Comment: Thanks @barryhoudini Would I also in the statement still look and check that the single values "c" or "d" are present even when I use the COUNTIF for the specific scenario when "a" and "b" are in the cell.

Comment: Thanks @Vityata I should have edited it and viewed it as such I think all on one line and looking like one statement confused me.

Comment: Seems I'm a bit stuck still, can't seem to nest the AND together.
Basically, I want the statement to be true and return a value if "a" OR "b" or "c" AND "d" are present in cell C7, otherwise return another value.

Comment: @Vityata Yes I did, I managed to get the TRUE/FALSE count but when I try to get that to then display the value I'm looking for it will return the value even if only one of the values are found.
'=AND(
 COUNT(SEARCH({"Android";"iOS"},C7)),
 COUNT(SEARCH({"Mobile Device","All Delivery Methods"},C7))
)'

I assume this is wrong. I think I'm a little confused how to use the COUNT, I get that we are trying to say that any COUNT values over 0 should return the true value, and if nothing matches then return the false but not sure how to define that.

Comment: @LoosSerine - your formula would return `TRUE` only if both conditions are `TRUE`. If one of them is `FALSE` it will return `FALSE`. This is what I have tried, it works quite ok: `=AND(COUNT(SEARCH({"Android";"iOS"},A1)), COUNT(SEARCH({"MobileDevice";"All Delivery Methods"},A1)))`

Comment: @Vityata Isn't that the same formula as the one I had? I still get the FALSE flag.
Also, rather than True and False, is there anyway to make that display other values instead.
Thanks

Comment: @LoosSerine - what do you have in cell `C7`?

Comment: C7 currently has: All Delivery Methods, -Android, -Amazon Fire TV, -iOS

But since it is a multi-select drop down list, it could be anything within that list.

Comment: @LoosSerine - you do not have neither of "MobileDevice" "All Delivery Methods", thus it returns `FALSE`. What do you mean with "multi-select drop down" list? The formula takes only the value, that is present in `C7`, the one on the list are not taken into account.

Comment: @Vityata C7 currently has "All Delivery Methods", see my previous comment with the values it currently has. What I mean is, its a drop down select that you can add to the list further. Therefore the C7 cell can have additional values added to whatever is already in that cell.

Comment: @LoosSerine - write a few scenarios for when the value is TRUE. E.g. Scenario 1 All Devices. Scenario 2 iOS or PC/Mac Scenario 3 Something else etc. I think we have different understanding of boolean logic.

Comment: Scenario 1: All Devices
Scenario 2: Mobile Devices
Scenario 3: Android AND iOS

if Any of the above is present in the cell C7 then return "Mobile DTC/ALL", if none of the scenarios are met, then return "No Devices".

Comment: @LoosSerine - `All Devices Scenario` -> What do we compare there? Do we simply give TRUE as an answer or we check something? The same goes for the other 3 scenarios. Write it in the question. :)